# Chrome capture visible tab gives messy result

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screen-capture, chromebook

I have a Chrome extension, where I'm using the `captureVisibleTab` method of the  `chrome.tabs` API to capture screenshots. I have tested the extension on 3 devices (Chromebooks) and I'm getting mixed results. Two of them work perfectly, but one always returns a completely malformed screenshot.

My code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function (_tab) {
        if (_tab.status == "complete" && _tab.active ) {
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab( function(dataUrl){

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas what could be the issue on that one device?

EDIT

Example of a bad screenshot:

[image: malformed screenshot taken by a Chrome extension]

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the device pixel ratio is higher on your 3rd device. This was an issue I was having with Retina displays when building a screenshot app. Basically, certain high-resolution displays have a higher ratio pixels per square inch. You're going to want to find window.devicePixelRatio and divide the context scale by that amount.

Assuming that you are using Canvas to draw the screenshot and capture it into an image, this little snippet should help show what you're going to want to do:

```
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            if(window.devicePixelRatio > 1){
                context.scale(1/window.devicePixelRatio, 1/window.devicePixelRatio);
            }
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that's not the case here. I checked and they all have same ratios.

Comment: Hmm. Could you edit your original post to include the resulting image from the 3rd device? I'm curious to see what the image looks like.

Comment: There is an example in my original post now.

Comment: Haha that's not at all what I was expecting. Out of curiosity, what are the model numbers for the 3 machines? You could try adjusting the quality; it's one of the optional parameters in captureVisibleTab https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-captureVisibleTab

I don't think that would fix it, but it's worth a try.